# Is it possible to make window for OpenGL ES 2.0 with GLFW 3.2.1 on Mac?

Tags: opengl-es, glfw

I'm struggling to make window with GLFW3.2.1 on Mac for OpenGL ES 2.0..
Is it possible to make OpenGL ES 2.0 window on macOS?

The Graphic card is using Iris Pro or Radeon Pro 455 they are have GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility.

The code is like below:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if (!glfwInit()) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n");
        getchar();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_OPENGL_ES_API);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 0);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    GLFWmonitor *monitor = glfwGetPrimaryMonitor();
    const GLFWvidmode *mode = glfwGetVideoMode(monitor);

    window = glfwCreateWindow(mode->width, mode->height, "Window", NULL, NULL);

    if (window == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,
                "Failed to open GLFW window.\n");
        getchar();
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    ...
```

I always failed to make window... Any hints are welcomed!

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr**: No this is not possible.

I'm struggling with the same. Currently this is due to an internal check in GLFW 3.2.1 that prevents you from being able to create an OpenGL ES context. Have a look at nsgl_context.m:

```
 if (ctxconfig->client == GLFW_OPENGL_ES_API)
{
    _glfwInputError(GLFW_API_UNAVAILABLE,
                    "NSGL: OpenGL ES is not available on OS X");
    return GLFW_FALSE;
}
```

Basically, if you request GLFW_OPENGL_ES_API, your window will always be null.

I'm currently looking for a way to work around this by including the OpenGL ES 2.0 libraries found on MoltenGL, but no luck so far.

https://moltengl.com/downloads/